# Deprecate term from term store using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to **deprecate** a Term from my term store using Microsoft Graph API.

I tried to update the term properties to achieve this using the [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-term-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) action as below but this is not working.

```
PATCH sites/{site-id}/termStore/sets/{set-id}/terms/{term-id}
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "deprecated": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "XX",
            "request-id": "XX",
            "client-request-id": "XX"
        }
    }
}
```

I do have the **TermStore.ReadWrite.All** permissions.

Is this even possible to do?
If yes, do you know how to do this?

Comment: I am looking into this

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this could be happening because your user doesn't have sufficient privileges for the group under which you are trying to update the term. Your user needs to be at least a '**contributor**' to the parent group of this term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the rights on the termset and I get a new error: 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "XX",
            "request-id": "XX",
            "client-request-id": "XX"
        }
    }
}
I will update the original post with this error.

Comment: Could you please share RequestId, clientRequestId, and timestamp for your Graph API call?